# Shortcut key for "Open file location" in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, file-management

I'm new to Windows (former Mac user) and using Windows 7 for about two months now.

I almost exclusively use the taskbar to navigate to files (i.e., I press the Win/meta key and start typing... my libraries and naming conventions make it pretty easy to get the correct file). Then I press enter and the file opens. Awesome.

But sometimes I want to see the file in its folder (i.e., maybe I want to rename, move, copy, etc.). To do this I need to mouse/trackpad over and right click to get the "Open in file location" options. Is there another way, short of searching for the folder name instead? Is there a hotkey/shortcut for "Open file location"? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution -- Type search phrase into task bar and arrow down to the appropriate entry. Then press the (context) menu key, and "i" for the "Open file location" entry. This isn't as good as a shortcut, but may be as good as it gets.

Comment: @Moab -- For most of the context items it shows the shortcut, underlines the letter for the hotkey, or you can try the first letter of the list item.

Comment: All these years and I never noticed the underline when using that key, which I rarely use, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using Mouse Button here: [Is there a keyboard shortcut for 'Open file location' within Windows Search?](https://superuser.com/questions/152090/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-open-file-location-within-windows-search/1088273#1088273)

Hope it can help you.