# Windows 7 search context how to leave it?

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-search

When I do search and click result and it is a folder I am still in search context. 
I see in location "> search results in [some folder] > [folder I have clicked]".

How to make it that when I click result I go to the folder location directly leaving the search mode/context?

Comment: I know what you mean; that is extremely frustrating. If you do a search and then open one of the folders in the results, then press `Alt+Up` to go to the parent, you go back to a search window instead. `>:-(`

Comment: Highlight the search result entry then Press context key, then i key, ....http://superuser.com/questions/231817/shortcut-key-for-open-file-location-in-windows-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can make it the default "click" action (without a 3rd party utility), but you can right-click the folder and select "Open folder location" to have it navigate to the real path, in the current window.

Comment: That is, well, some solution. Maybe there is some key in registry for it? But how would it be called?