# Open Windows Explorer when searching for file in Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Mac OS X has a **COMMAND + ENTER** keyboard shortcut in Spotlight, that opens **Finder** to the path to a file that you just searched for.

I'm looking for the equivalent on Windows.

What do I press to open Windows Explorer to the currently selected file, in the Start Menu search?

[image: Windows 10 Start Menu]

Comment: SHIFT + F10, Down, ENTER is one option, but not ideal.

Comment: you can also look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/231817/shortcut-key-for-open-file-location-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the search result and click 'open file location' or 'open containing folder', or mouseover the search result and hit shift + f10 to right click it, then either use the arrow keys to select 'open file location', or try the alt+ underlined letter shortcuts (aka [Access Keys](http://www.speakeasysolutions.com/blog/2010/06/19/underline-keyboard-shortcuts-and-access-keys/))

Alternitivey you can add a context menu item to handle file extentions if there is no such option as 'open file location'

Follow [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/) but replace notepad.exe with explorer.exe