# How can I open file location in a new window in win10 search result?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Just as this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/152090/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-open-file-location-within-windows-search), however, how can I "Open File Location" in a new windows instead of in the old one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while klicking, or pressing Enter, on Open File Location.

Comment: Thanks, but how do u know that? In any document?

Comment: It was an educated guess. ;-)